# JS variable undefined error after the API response in protractor

Tags: node.js, json, protractor, httprequest, httpresponse

I need to perform action on the response from the API response. I am able to process the response get the desired result. But when I try to get the variable outside that function I am getting the variable as undefined. I need to return the variable from the function.
My code

```
  RetrieveLatestRunIDFromTestSuiteDetails : async function(Project, TestEnvironment, JenkinsJob, TestExecutionID) {
  
        var testSuiteStatuses ;
        var input={
                 "jenkinsJob": JenkinsJob,
                 "project": Project,
                 "testEnvironment": TestEnvironment,
                 "TestExecutionID":TestExecutionID
             };
             const data=JSON.stringify(input);
             const options= {
                 host: host,
                 path: '/api/db/getRunIDFromTestSuiteDetails',
                 method: 'PUT',
                 headers: {
                     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                 }
             }
             const request = await https.request(options, (res) => {
                 console.log(`statusCode from RetrieveLatestRunIDFromTestSuiteDetails ::  ${res.statusCode}`);
                 
                 res.on('data', (d) => {

                     process.stdout.write("Response Data from RetrieveLatestRunIDFromTestSuiteDetails:: " + d);
                     var jsonobj=JSON.parse(d);
                     testSuiteStatuses=jsonobj["buildID"];
                     console.log("build id number:"+testSuiteStatuses);                                       
                       
                 })           
                
            })           
             console.log("test suite number that needs to return:"+testSuiteStatuses);
             request.write(data);
             request.end();
             return testSuiteStatuses; 
           
        }
```

On the console I am getting

```
test suite number that needs to return:undefined
statusCode from RetrieveLatestRunIDFromTestSuiteDetails ::  200
Response Data from RetrieveLatestRunIDFromTestSuiteDetails:: {"buildID":48}build id number:48
```

test suite number that needs to return is executing before the any other statement.
Can someone help me to return the variable "testSuiteStatuses" .

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you need to do. First, wrap the entire function in a Promise. Secondly, move your return statement into a `res.on('end', () => {})` and resolve the value in there. Notice I also removed async/await from your function. You don't need it here.

```
RetrieveLatestRunIDFromTestSuiteDetails : function(Project, TestEnvironment, JenkinsJob, TestExecutionID) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let testSuiteStatuses;
    const input = {
      "jenkinsJob": JenkinsJob,
      "project": Project,
      "testEnvironment": TestEnvironment,
      "TestExecutionID":TestExecutionID
    };

    const data=JSON.stringify(input);

    const options= {
      host: host,
      path: '/api/db/getRunIDFromTestSuiteDetails',
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };

    const request = https.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log(`statusCode from RetrieveLatestRunIDFromTestSuiteDetails ::  ${res.statusCode}`);

      res.on('data', (d) => {

        process.stdout.write("Response Data from RetrieveLatestRunIDFromTestSuiteDetails:: " + d);
        var jsonobj=JSON.parse(d);
        testSuiteStatuses=jsonobj["buildID"];
        console.log("build id number:"+testSuiteStatuses);

      });

      res.on('end', () => {
        console.log("test suite number that needs to return:"+testSuiteStatuses);
        resolve(testSuiteStatuses);
      });

    });

    request.write(data);
    request.end();
  });
}
```

Comment: In order to return a variable we need to use promise? I am new tp protractor and JS. I started working/learning recently.

Comment: For async stuff, yes, you want to return a Promise. In this case you would probably have some code that calls this function that looks something like `const runId = await RetrieveLatestRunIDFromTestSuiteDetails(myProject, myEnv, myJenkinsJob, myExecutionId);`

Comment: Yes I called the same way to get the value. Thank you.